# Caching jQuery variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just read that if you are referring to the same DOM element over and over in a function it is better to cache them in a local variable like :

`var btn = $('#clearBtn');`

I have followed this where necessary but when accessing back this object I have always used `$(btn).somemethod();` although we can access this directly like `btn.somemethod();`

I just need to know whether this will have a negative impact ?

Comment: You make an unnecessary function call. It's not "harmful", just unnecessary. You wouldn't do `$($('#clearBtn'))` either, would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point in passing the jQuery object through the jQuery constructor. It's just wasteful. If the dollar sign looks nice to you, just prepend it to the variable name and use `$btn` in place of `$(btn)`:

```
var $btn = $('#clearBtn');
```

Comment: I have very little knowledge on how internal processes take place within the jQuery lib. Do you mean that it runs unnecessary functions and waste resources?

Comment: @crazyMAN: `$` is a function. You run it unnecessarily by passing `btn` to it.

Answer (score 0):

`btn.somemethod();` will work, and is the correct way, since `btn` is already a jQuery object.

Besides, unless you call `$('#clearBtn');` a lot of times in a short period of time, I wouldn't bother caching it.